# MVC View Image URL: Cannot convert lambda expression to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

How can I load URL path from database from to view with foreign key "BAZ_ID"?

IMAGE_URL:

> ~/UploadImg/Untitled.png

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Bazar()
    {
        WebEntities db = new WebEntities();
        var data = db.bazar.Include(c => c.images);
        return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

And view:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src= "@Url.Content(modelItem => item.images.Where(a => a.BAZ_ID == item.ID).Select(b => b.IMAGE_URL).FirstOrDefault())" width="150" height="150" />
        </div>
```

In view I get error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Remove the leading `modelItem => `. But your queries belong in the controller, not the view and you should be passing a view model that contains a property for the image url.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` is not guaranteed to return an object that is not `null`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke consider adding you comment as answer - so many times I see your great answers and I can't "properly" upvote them ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) method requires a string as the parameter, not a lambda expression.

You can change the code in you loop to (drop the leading `modelItem =>`)

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(item.images.Where(a => a.BAZ_ID == item.ID).Select(b => b.IMAGE_URL).FirstOrDefault())" ... />
```

However, queries belong in the controller, not the view, and your view model should contain a property (say) `string ImageUrl` which you populate in the controller, and then in the view

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(item.ImageUrl)" ... />
```